# jQuery remove fixed class when scrolling back up

Tags: jquery, fixed-header-tables

I am having some issue with removeClass() in jquery. I have read many posts about this and still can't find my mistake. Any pointers from community would be most welcome!

When scrolling down in this snippet, the fixed class will be added to the blue bar. When scrolling back up, it is not removed. I don't understand it. Anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on("scroll", (event) => {
    const $header = $('.table-header');
    const distanceToTop = $header.offset().top; // find distance to top
    const y = $(window).scrollTop(); // find current scroll position
    if (y >= distanceToTop) $header.addClass('fixed');
    else $header.removeClass('fixed');
  });
});
```

```css
div.table {
  min-height: 2000px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}

.table-header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-container mt-5 mb-2">
    <h1 class="h4">Toggle fixed class</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row table-header relative bg-primary text-light mb-1">
      This is the fixed div
    </div>
    <div id="contacts-list" class="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `distanceToTop` variable outside the scroll function, it'll always be equal to your `y` variable when you'll scroll down.

You need to instanciate your offset top of table header only one time, when you scroll down, the offset top of the table is equal to your window scroll top.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  const distanceToTop = $('.table-header').offset().top; // find distance to top
  $(window).on("scroll", (event) => {
    const $header = $('.table-header');
    const y = $(window).scrollTop(); // find current scroll position
    if (y >= distanceToTop) $header.addClass('fixed');
    else $header.removeClass('fixed');
  });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const distanceToTop = $('.table-header').offset().top; // find distance to top
  $(window).on("scroll", (event) => {
    const $header = $('.table-header');
    const y = $(window).scrollTop(); // find current scroll position
    if (y >= distanceToTop) $header.addClass('fixed');
    else $header.removeClass('fixed');
    
    console.log(y);
    console.log(distanceToTop);
  });
});
```

```css
div.table {
  min-height: 2000px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}

.table-header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-container mt-5 mb-2">
    <h1 class="h4">Toggle fixed class</h1>
    <div class="relative text-right">
      <input name="search-input" id="search-input" class="" type="search" placeholder="Search a contact ...">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row table-header relative bg-primary text-light mb-1">
      Fixed div
    </div>
    <div id="contacts-list" class="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Wish I did helped you

Comment: Hah. That's logic. I understand now. Thanks! :)

Comment: No problem @TVBZ, glad to help you, if it did answer to you, put this answer as solution please :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after you added the fixed class to the table header, its offset().top will be always equal to the window.scrollTop(), since it's fixed to the top of the viewport. Try to save the original offset to a global variable when first adding the class, then calculate the distance only from the window.scrollTop() and this variable.

Also you can cache your selector outside of the scroll function:

```
var original_table_top = -1;
var $header = null;

function OnWindowScroll() {
    //Check if we already have the position
    if (original_table_top == -1) {

        //You have to add the window.scroll pos to it, since what if the page is scrolled when it loaded.
        original_table_top = $header.offset().top + $(window).scrollTop();
    }

    const y = $(window).scrollTop(); // find current scroll position

    if (y >= original_table_top) $header.addClass('fixed');
    else $header.removeClass('fixed');
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $header = $('.table-header'); //Cache selector

    $(window).scroll(OnWindowScroll);

    //Call the function when the page is loaded
    OnWindowScroll();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is, distancetotop is not aletered until it reaches nav pos when it reaches value is changed to 0 after that `if` never  fails so else part will never get executed .

this is a solution i move variable initialisation to  top

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $header = $('.table-header');
  const distanceToTop = $header.offset().top;
  $(window).on("scroll", (event) => {
    
    var y = $(window).scrollTop(); // find current scroll position
    if (y >= distanceToTop) $header.addClass('fixed');
    if (y < distanceToTop) $header.removeClass('fixed');
    console.log(distanceToTop);
  });
});
```

```css
div.table {
  min-height: 2000px;
  background: #b0b0b0;
}

.table-header.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 5px rgba(57, 63, 72, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header-container mt-5 mb-2">
    <h1 class="h4">Toggle fixed class</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row table-header relative bg-primary text-light mb-1">
      This is the fixed div
    </div>
    <div id="contacts-list" class="">

    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```